# class UIInstance getElementById(id) returns a Generic object if the widget is a ListBox

Tags: listbox, google-apps-script

I have an app, which display a panel with fields filled from a document.

The user edit the fields, and the updated values updates the document.
Everything is working, with one exception.

The panel has several TextBox and a ListBox. When the panel is displayed, a function fills the values in the text boxes. It uses getElementById in order to get the widgets.

I would like to show the ListBox with the proper value already selected. Unfortunately, the getElementById on this widget returns a Generic, and the standard methods of ListBox aren't available.

Here is a fragment of code:

```
function fillSingleDocFields(meta, app) {
  var eleTitolo = app.getElementById('idnomeDoc');   // OK!
  eleTitolo.setText(meta.titolo);


  var lbTipologia = app.getElementById('idtipologia');
  Logger.log(lbTipologia);                          // KO
  setListBoxSelected(lbTipologia, meta.tipologia); 
  return app;
}
```

the setListBoxSelected function fails on the first ListBox specific method:

```
function setListBoxSelected(lb, value) {
  for (var i=0;i<lb.getItemCount();i++)  // runtime error
  { 
    if ( lb.getValue(i) == value) 
      lb.setSelectedIndex(i);
  }  
}
```

The error is (translated from italian): no getItemCount function in Generic object.

Here is the code execution transcript:

```
[13-07-08 12:13:01:691 CEST] (class).getElementById([idnomeDoc]) [0 secondi]
[13-07-08 12:13:01:692 CEST] (class).setText([mio titolone 2]) [0 secondi]
[13-07-08 12:13:01:692 CEST] (class).getElementById([idtipologia]) [0 secondi]
[13-07-08 12:13:01:692 CEST] (class).toString() [0 secondi]
[13-07-08 12:13:01:692 CEST] (class).toString() [0 secondi]
[13-07-08 12:13:01:692 CEST] Logger.log([Generic, []]) [0 secondi]
[13-07-08 12:13:01:693 CEST] (class).toString() [0 secondi]
[13-07-08 12:13:01:735 CEST] Esecuzione non riuscita: TypeError: Impossibile trovare la     funzione getItemCount nell'oggetto Generic. (riga 29, file "Controller") [0.404 secondi di esecuzione totale]
```

A possible solution could be to set the selected value in the ListBox when I create it, but unfortunately, at that moment, that values is unknown.

My questions are:

- is  it possible to cast the result of getElementById? (I don't think so, looking to similar questions);
- is there something wrong in my approach? Or is the getElementById always returning Generic objects (this contrast with other answers).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not with the generic widget returned by `getElementById`. Which, even though does not autocomplete specific methods anymore, still accepts that you call it.

The issue is that the `ListBox` object does **not** have a `getItemCount` method. Here's is a quick test:

```js
function testList() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Test');
  var list = app.createListBox().addItem('test');
  Logger.log(list.getItemCount());
  return app.add(list);
}
```

And for that matter, it also does not have a `getValue` method.

Usually Apps Script widgets does not have such methods (for you to get things). You have to either know that beforehand or get it from a callback-element, by inspecting the parameter passed to your callback-handler function.

Comment: It's clear. I was hoping that the methods of the same widget from GWT were supported. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no implementation of this function. (see [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1537))

But you can pass values ​​through the callback in handler function. See example.

```
function ui(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var lb = app.createListBox().setName('lb'); //not id
  lb.addItem('first item').addItem('second item'); 

  var hndlr = app.createServerHandler('send')
                 .addCallbackElement(lb);     //be sure to add callback

  var btn = app.createButton('SEND');
  btn.addClickHandler(hndlr);

  app.add(lb).add(btn);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
}
function send(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var lbValue = e.parameter.lb;    //selected value

  //do somethink with lbValue
  app.add(app.createLabel(lbValue));
  return app;
}
```

Comment: I saw the issue; as suggested, perhaps the best way is to "rebuild" the list of values each time, setting the selected item while I add values to the list.

Comment: I have already implemented the handlar callback mechanism in order to retrieve the selected value, without problems. Tks